# Evaluating the length of a list with an integer in an if statement issue

Tags: python, list

Bit of a dumb issue and question, but I cannot figure out why this cannot evaluate to true despite the returned values are both integers.

I am trying to evaluate whether or not the length of a list **'len(Some_List)'** equals an integer **'Tally_Count'**. The length of 'Some_List' will always be different. It is not static as different values are passed in and/or taken out.

The IDs of the objects are different so using 'is' is not possible for this situation. The IDs will always be different.

Is there a reason why '==' will not work despite both being integers? Is it because of how the value is being returned from 'len()' despite it being returned as an integer?  I am using python 3.7.

Anyway to fix or have it evaluate properly?

```
if Tally_Count == len(Some_List):
     do something here
else: 
     do the other thing
```

Comment: What you're doing should work.  Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  There isn't enough information in the post for anyone else to reproduce this.

Comment: Guess: you’re setting `Tally_Count = input()`, and it’s really a string that looks like an int.

Comment: Alternate guess: you’ve accidentally redefined `len` somewhere and now it return a str.

Comment: first check `print( type(Tally_Count) )` to see if you really have integer or string with digits. If you have string then you have to convert it to integer `Tally_Count = int(Tally_Count)`

Answer (score 2):

I do not see how is it not working for you.
Upon trying something similar, I got the expected results. A screenshot is shown below:

[image]

Code Snippet:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
tally_count = 5

if tally_count == len(l):
    print("Equal")
else:
    print("Not Equal")
```

Output:

```
Equal
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this may be, you assign `float` instead of `int` to `Tally_Count` by somehow.